# Comparing two NSIntegers results in < nil > instead of false

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, comparison, nsinteger

having a weird issue comparing two NSIntegers after doing a subtraction, any ideas why this comparison returns "< nil >" instead of false? I checked to make sure I had values for all variables in the debugger

```
    NSInteger totalPhotosLeft = self.totalPhotosInRoll - self.currentPhotosFetchedCount;
    if (self.enumerateCount < totalPhotosLeft) {
        ...//never goes here, comparison above always returns < nil >
    }
```

My properties

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentPhotosFetchedCount;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger enumerateCount;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger totalPhotosInRoll;
```

viewDidLoad

```
self.currentPhotosFetchedCount = 60;
self.enumerateCount = 15;
self.totalPhotosInRoll = 65;
```

Comment: What do you mean that it returns "<nil>"?

Comment: When i check in the debugger:
po self.enumerateCount < totalPhotsLeft
I get "<nil>"

Comment: Use `p self.enumerateCount < totalPhotsLeft`. `po` is for `print object`. This isn't an object.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! ill write it up as an answer

Answer (score 0):

While debugging I was using po instead of p. po is for printing out objects, p is for printing out in general.

Thanks to @rmaddy for figuring that out so quickly